# How do i fix glide with keyword error in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

Im trying to use glide on my fragment but "with" keyword is getting an error on my IDE.

Here is my code

```
val stringUri = this.arguments?.getString("uriFoto")
val uri = stringUri!!.toUri()
Glide.with(context).load(uri).into(binding.ivProfil)
```

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjcvu.png)

and here is my glide classs code

```
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule

@GlideModule
class Glide : AppGlideModule()  {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check import package of glide library.
import the below two packages

1)import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
2)import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions

Comment: i already did that on my fragment. it worked after i reopen my android studio, maybe just a bug